# Is my book interesting and my writing eloquent enough?

Tags: style, book, reviews, criticism

I'm young and this is my first attempt at a book. Comment here or on the document itself, it doesn't matter to me.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/16MXV41o324ZYMPjvRQqjQ5XsuK_0IT7qJypJFf-8_8A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. Stack Exchange is not like other sites. We are a Q&A site, not a discussion board or an online workshop. You may have some luck on Critique Circle. https://www.critiquecircle.com/ We do handle some critique questions if they are phrased according to our guidelines, but this doesn't meet those critieria, and will be closed.

Comment: @NicolasCage FWIW the opening looked well-written and engaging to me --I wouldn't have necessarily guessed a young author.

Answer (score 1):

Whether it is interesting does not matter so much. If you think it is interesting, then there is a very good chance that someone interested in your book's genre will also find it interesting.

You should be more worried about whether it makes sense. You appear to have a few too many adjectives in here, you are describing some objects with two to three words which are synonyms. Cut these.

Also make sure there are no spelling or grammatical errors in your book. Reread it and edit it as many times as you want. It will help when you are looking for a publisher.

I can only see the first chapter of your book? Where is the rest?

It is really good that you are attempting this, but please keep all of the above in mind.